# c++ analog of c# "project reference"

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

My solution contains several c# projects.
It's easy to add "refernce" from one project to another(References-Add Reference-Project). After that I can use classes from referenced project.

How can I do the same for native c++ projects? What kind of projects should I create? Console application/DLL/Static library?

Comment: The closest concept in C++ would be to have your DLL/EXE project reference another DLL one.  However there is a considerable difference in how this works in C# and C++.  You will likely need to do a bit of reading before you will be able to complete this project successfully.  I would start by reading thins http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are two things in C / C++ :

- Headers file, that will tell your program what they can use (e.g. class, function prototype declaration)
- Implementation, either as a

  - source code that you recompile with your program
  - static lib (.lib on windows)
  - dynamic lib (.dll on windows)

You need both to compile your program with parts from another project.
If you only need a class from a big library and you have the source of this library it may be easier to reference the file corresponding to this class (and its dependencies of course). But if you need more, you should add the other project's directory to the include path of your current project in VCC, and link against the library (either static or dynamic, according to your needs).